# Detecting incoming SMS using BroadcastReceiver not working

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I'm developing an Android app which will detect and scan the SMS for its content even when my application is closed. I know that BroadcastReceiver is the solution for this and I've developed the code, but unfortunately not getting the output as expected.

Here is my Activity file

```
public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = SMSBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String SMS_CONTENT = "sms_content";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());

    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String smsBody = c.getString(12);
    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS RECEIVED:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(context, smsBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I've also included these lines in my Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

<receiver android:name=".SMSBroadcastReceiver">
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

How can I find out what is going wrong and why I'm not able to Toast the incoming SMS?

Comment: `Telephony` needs to be capitalized in `"android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"` in the manifest. That is, it should be `"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"`. Also, please note that the new message may not have been written to the Provider when you receive this broadcast.

Comment: Take a look at this project: https://github.com/vivdub/DynamicSMSReceiver/commit/e807dfa0a2f02da553e4d68096a6842ad8351d06

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Actually, the only problem was I was not starting the broadcast anywhere. I just added the lines

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(MyActivity.this, SMSBroadcastReceiver.class));
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer - did you not try sending a SMS to your device to test your receiver??

Answer (score 0):

In you onReceive method you should do something like the following code to read the sms content:

```
if (intent != null && intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs;
    String sender;
    if (bundle != null) {
        try {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                // Here you have the sender(phone number)
                sender = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                // you have the sms content in the msgBody
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

Does this help?

Comment: Hey Mike! I made changes in my code as you said, but still it doesn't work... Also, can you plz explain me how to check if the new messsage is being written to the Provider on broadcast???

Comment: FYI `createFromPdu()` has been deprecated. Take care